# Remove elements of an array of type Results (of Realm type)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm

Consider a function which which assigns value to an array like so...

```
  fileprivate func getMessages() {
    if let myId = recipientGrp?.id,
      let array = realm()?.objects(TheMessage.self)
        .filter("ownerId = '\(myId)' || receiverId = '\(myId)'")
        .sorted(byKeyPath: "id", ascending: true) {
      allMessages = array
    }
  }
```

Here, `allMessages` is the array into which values are added. Also `allMessages` is declared like so....

```
var allMessages: Results<TheMessage>?
```

What I want to achieve is  I want to remove all elements of the array `allMessages`. `allMessages.removeAll` doesn’t work. So how can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you trying to delete the query results from realm? Have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1):

Because `allMessages` is a `Results<Message>`, you need to remove those objects from Realm to actually remove them.

```
let realm = // get a realm
try realm.write {
    realm.delete(allMessages)
}
// allMessages will automatically become empty at this point.
```